# How to download files in an Android application to SD card so that it is accessible for other applications as well

Tags: java, android, download, android-sdcard

How can someone download files to SD card with the Download Manager, so that it is accessible to other applications, too (something that works in modern Android distributions)?

A working code example would be highly appreciated.

**PS:** In case you need some source, [you can have a look at issue 117 of the free software Zapp](https://github.com/mediathekview/zapp/issues/117).

Comment: What if there in no removable micro SD card inserted?

Comment: Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and allow the user to choose where your app should download the user's content.

Comment: If there's no micro SD card inserted an exception could be thrown or it could be exited from the method. This isn't the important part here. `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` doesn't work with the download manager. I missed this in the original post but I will update it accordingly.